# My displayLink stays black screen

Tags: 16.04, display, displaylink

I have ubuntu 16.04 LTS when I connect my docking station to use my two monitors connected to it they stay with the black screen and I can only see the mouse pointer, if I try to pass a window does not show up, I already install DisplayLink and it does not work